# IOS automation script error

Tags: ios, automation

What wrong with this automation script.I have only one textfield where user enters his email id.Everytime i run this,i keep getting "Wrong number of text fields".

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
target.logElementTree();

//var textfieldscount = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()["UserText"];

var textfieldscount = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()[0];

var count = textfieldscount.length;

//var count = view.textFields();

if(count!=1){
        UIALogger.logFail("Wrong number of text fields");
}else{
        UIALogger.logFail("Right number of text fields");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a single Test field on your app window it's better to handle it using the code below (if you simply want to check whether it's visible and has got a correct name):

```
    var txt_field_name = textfieldscount .name();

    if (textfieldscount .isVisible () && txt_field_name .match("UserText")){
      UIALogger.logPass("Txt field is on a screen");
      ... YOUR_CODE_HERE...
    } else {
      UIALogger.logFail("Wrong number of text fields");
    }
```